# Remove " from a string to create a variable?

Tags: python, string, function, variables

Is there a possibility to create a function which creates variables from strings like this:

```
def createNewVariable(Name, Value):
    Name - #strings# = Value

createNeewVariable("Var1", 20)
print(Var1)
```

I want to remove the `"` to get a variable and then print the value.

---

The original problem is that I wanted to create objects of a class by creating variables with a function. That's also the reason why I asked how to create variable from strings.

The specific problem is here:

```
class bankacc:
    balance = 0
    number = 0

    def __init__(self, balance, number):
        self.balance = balance
        self.number = number

    def pay(self, value):
        self.balance = self.balance + value



bankacc1 = bankacc(0,0)
bankacc1.pay(100)

def createbankacc(Name, Balance, Number):
    Name = bankacc(Balance, Number)

createbankacc("Peter", 100, 1)
```

The function should create a bankaccount object with the name Peter, the balance of 100 and the number 1.

Comment: No, there isn't. And you almost certainly don't want to do that.

Comment: So there is no way to create variables automatically?

Comment: why it's not recommended? Because of errors or problems?

Comment: @user120242 in the general case, you cannot. You can, in CPython, modify the *global namespace* directly. But you cannot modify, for example, a local namespace

Comment: @ProProgrammee69 because it leads to hard to reason-about code and it is almost never the right solution to whatever problem you are asking. If you want to associate a string with another object, then use *a map*, i.e. a `dict`.

Comment: ok thank you especially for the quick answers! I am really new in python (only 1 year of school education in python) I hopefully will find a solution for my problem

Comment: @ProProgrammee69 you should *ask about your problem*. What is it that you are *actually trying to do?*

Comment: I will create a new question for my problem where I wanted to create the variable creator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use `globals()['Var1'] = 20` but it is highly not recommended

Edit: by recommended, I mean that there is almost always a better way to tackle a problem than using his method.

Comment: true, this answer is technically correct, assuming OP wants to insert into the global namespace and not the surrounding scope of the fuction (which might not be the global one).